# Efficient time rounding function

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a custom postgresql function to round TIMESTAMPTZ fields to an arbitrary interval with the basic algorithm of `round(timestamp / interval) * interval` and some research, I found a solution:

`SELECT to_timestamp(round((extract('epoch' from timestamp)) / interval) * interval)`

it works. My question: is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Could you give an example of an interval, a timestamp, and the result? What are the performance problems you're having?

Comment: @Schwern i.e. `SELECT to_timestamp(round((extract('epoch' from '2022-01-04T23:28:45.000Z'::timestamptz)) / 30) * 30);` -> `2022-01-04 23:29:00.000000`

Comment: To an arbitrary number of seconds, I see. And what performance problems are you having?

Comment: @Schwern None. I'm asking if there is a better way of doing this, I don't have any experience with postgres functions, for example I'm unsure of whether `extract('epoch' FROM ts)` is the best way to convert a timestamptz to epoch

Comment: Yes, there's essentially no cost. A timestamptz is stored as the number of microseconds since the epoch, plus a time zone.

Comment: It's pretty unreadable indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Look this like a template:
[Round a timestamp to the nearest 5-minute mark.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Round_time)

The sample usage:

```sql
postgres=# select now(), round_time('2010-09-17 16:48');
              now              |       round_time       
-------------------------------+------------------------
 2010-09-19 08:36:31.701919+02 | 2010-09-17 16:50:00+02
(1 row)

postgres=# select now(), round_time('2010-09-17 16:58');
              now              |       round_time       
-------------------------------+------------------------
 2010-09-19 08:36:43.860858+02 | 2010-09-17 17:00:00+02
(1 row)

postgres=# select now(), round_time('2010-09-17 16:57');
              now              |       round_time       
-------------------------------+------------------------
 2010-09-19 08:36:53.273612+02 | 2010-09-17 16:55:00+02
(1 row)

postgres=# select now(), round_time('2010-09-17 23:58');
             now              |       round_time       
------------------------------+------------------------
 2010-09-19 08:37:09.41387+02 | 2010-09-18 00:00:00+02
(1 row)
```